# checking/accessing dynamically created objects in QML

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt4, qml

Is there any way to check existence and access a dynamically created object in QML/javascript (without using C++)?

I'm trying to create an application with an interface similar to a map - given an key and a object, my application must locate if an object with the key exists and overwrite with the new object. If it doesn't, the app must create a new object and associate with the key.

The documentation says that dynamically managed objects doesn't have IDs, and the only way I found to access them was by using objectName, which seems to require C++ application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript object as a map. You can't directly manipulate it in QML, but you can move all code to handle this object into JavaScript file and include it as a module.
Here is a simple example:

Map.js:

```
var _map = new Object()

function value(key) {
    return _map[key]
}

function setValue(key, value) {
    _map[key] = value
}

function remove(key) {
    delete _map[key]
}

function keys() {
    return Object.keys(_map)
}

function process() {
    for (var key in _map) {
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

QML example:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import "Map.js" as Map

Item {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        Map.setValue("test", "hello")
        console.log("test = ", Map.value("test"))
        Map.remove("test", "hello")
        console.log("test = ", Map.value("test"))
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
test =  hello
test =  undefined
```

Comment: It worked as expected! thanks. Also is there any way to iterate through the whole map? I need to change values on all objects at same time...

Comment: @Ishida: Yes, there is even two ways :) You can define in the Map.js function, that returns list, containing all keys from map (also you can write function, that return all values, if needed) and then process that list. Or you can process the map directly in the Map.js. I have updated example with two function to iterate Map. Also, in process() you can iterate not only by keys, but also by values - just replace "for" with "for each".